# Custom object array of pointers all points to the same object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

This is my first post, so sorry if it is messy.

I want to dynamically add custom objects `Pixra` that I created in an `NSMutableArray`. Because it uses an interface, I instanciate my objects with a pointer as so : `Pixra* pix = [Pixra alloc];`.

When I parse my array, I can see that all the pointers I added points to the same object because the values of the property `quality` is the same for all the element of the array. Here is my implementation of the loop that adds the element in the array.

```
NSMutableArray* imagesRaw = [NSMutableArray array];
double j=0.0;
for (UIImage* img in images){
  Pixra* pix = [Pixra alloc];
  [pix setMatrix:img];
  [pix setQuality:j];
  [imagesRaw addObject:pix];
  cout << [imagesRaw[0] getQuality] << "\n";
  j++;
}
```

The console log shows that the quality is iterating while it shouldn't because I only display the first element of the array.

Pixra.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Pixra.h"
@implementation Pixra

UIImage* matrix;
double quality;

-(void) setMatrix:(UIImage*)matrixArg{
  matrix = matrixArg;
}
-(UIImage*) getMatrix{
  return matrix;
}
-(void) setQuality:(double)qualityArg{
  quality = qualityArg;
}
-(double) getQuality{
  return quality;
}
-(id) pixraInit:(UIImage*)img:(double)quality{
  self = [super init];
  self.matrix = img;
  self.quality = quality;
  return self;
}
+(instancetype) pixraInit:(UIImage*)img:(double)quality{
  Pixra* pix = [[Pixra alloc] pixraInit:img :quality];
  return pix;
}
@end
```

Pixra.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Pixra;
@interface Pixra : NSObject
-(void) setMatrix:(UIImage*)matrixArg;
-(UIImage*) getMatrix;
-(void) setQuality:(double)qualityArg;
-(double) getQuality;
+(instancetype) pixraInit:(UIImage*)img :(double)quality;
@end
```

As you can see, I tried to do it with an initalizer that returns the instance but it didn't work either.
How can I create pointers on different instances of my custom objects ?

Comment: Is it typo? `cout << [imagesRaw[0] getQuality] << "\n";` you're printing for zeroth index only

Comment: It is not a typo, I use this to check whether or not the first instance added in the array updates his quality. By doing it, I can see that every time I add an object in my array, it does increment while it shouldn't

Comment: Have you tried `Pixra* pix = [[Pixra alloc] init];` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, without success, I really don't understand where the problem comes from

Comment: @Chocobouc You are aware that adding an object adds it to the END of an array, not the beginning right? The first object in an array will always be the same, regardless of adding new objects. You need to use `imagesRaw[j]` or `imagesRaw[(int)imagesRaw.count]`, not `imagesRaw[0]`

Comment: Yes, I know that, I think I'm not clear enough. What I do here with `cout << [imagesRaw[0] getQuality] << "\n";` is printing the quality of the first element I added to the array at each loop. Because addObject add an object to the end of the array, the first element should always be the same and keep it's initial quality value which is 0.0 . However, this value iterates at each loop from 0.0 to 849.0 but it shouldn't !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write in the class implementation file like this, the compiler takes it as global variables. There is only one block of memory for each one.

```
UIImage* matrix;
double quality;
```

With these *properties*, all the `Pixra` object instances use the global variables to save them, it used in `Sington Instance` design pattern generally.

So how to correct it? If you are looking for the right properties to save the `matrix` and `quality` value for each `Pixra` instance, use `@property` like this.

```
@interface Pixra : NSObject

@property (strong) UIImage *matrix;
@property (assign) CGFloat quality;

@end
```

Note that this property implementation has covered the `setMatrix` and `matrix` property method. Check out more detail about [Objective-C Class Property](https://www.google.com/?q=Objective-C%20Class%20Property) in google.

Comment: Or if you don't want to create properties then you can use `@implementation Pixra : NSObject {
UIImage* matrix;
double quality; }` syntax.

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia It should be `@implementation Pixra { UIImage* matrix; double quality; }`, I think.

Comment: Oh yes, `: NSObject` shouldn't be with `@implementation`. Right? or something else missing?

Comment: That's it, I should have read the docs more carefully, I implemented a solution with a struct but I'm going to use this instead. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `init`

```
Pixra* pix = [Pixra alloc];
```

From documentation of [NSObject's init() method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init):

> An object isn’t ready to be used until it has been initialized.
>
> In some cases, a custom implementation of the init() method might return a substitute object. **You must therefore always use the object returned by init(), and not the one returned by alloc or allocWithZone:**, in subsequent code

So replace

```
Pixra* pix = [Pixra alloc];
```

with

```
Pixra* pix = [[Pixra alloc] init];
```

or

```
Pixra* pix = [Pixra new];
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried with `Pixra* pix = [Pixra new];` but the cout still iterates